# How to use Meteor with Jade, Flow Router and Blaze?

Tags: meteor, pug, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm trying to make Jade work with Meteor's Flow Router and Blaze. Somehow it doesn't work for me. I'm pretty sure it's just something small that I don't notice.

HTML versions of home.jade and layout.jade files give a proper, working result.

According to [this](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/issues/75), there used to be a problem, but it was solved in 0.2.9 release of mquandalle:jade.

$ meteor list

```
blaze                2.1.2  Meteor Reactive Templating library
kadira:blaze-layout  2.0.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRou...
kadira:flow-router   2.3.0  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
meteor-platform      1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your...
mquandalle:jade      0.4.3  Jade template language
```

layout.jade

```
template(name="layout")
  +Template.dynamic(template="main")
```

home.jade

```
template(name="home")
  p Looks like working!
```

routes.js

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout', {main: 'home'});
  }
});
```

The result:

```
<body>
  <div id="__blaze-root">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fyi, [CoffeeScript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/coffeescript) is like Jade for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, since then I switched to CoffeeScript and I use it with pleasure, now I find CS+Jade my favorite combo for Meteor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, it is just a subtle detail issue: you should not use quotes around the `main` parameter in your layout template:

```
template(name="layout")
  +Template.dynamic(template=main)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working fine. And here I was starting to think of sticking to pure HTML.

Comment: how can you pass variables to the dynamic call? Like this: `+template(data='abcdef' moredata='moreabc')` or in this case `+main(date='abcd')`?